# Why is the height of Text SwiftUI View different when setting the frame's width vs it's maxWidth when using fixedSize()?

Tags: swiftui

Why does the height of Text SwiftUI View expand correctly to allow for displaying the content when setting the width but it collapses to a single line when setting the maxWidth of it's frame?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Long Text Long Text Long Text Long Text Long Text Long Text Long Text Long Text Long Text")
                .background(Color.blue)
            Text("Short Text")
                .background(Color.green)
        }
        // .frame(width: 400) 
        // .frame(maxWidth: 400)
        .fixedSize()
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

with `.frame(width: 400)`:

[image: width[1]]

with `.frame(maxWidth: 400)`:

[image: maxWidth]

Comment: Upvoted your question. But consider - how likely is it the in less than 2 week Apple gives us SwiftUI 2.0? Not sure if your were part to the *painful* things Swift 1-3 brought us (and for some that includes Swift 4) but this kind of question (particularly if it's a version 1 "behavior") may be moot in a couple of weeks....

Comment: Thank you for the upvote. In a way I agree that this question maybe be somewhat redundant in the next 2 weeks, at least for iOS 14 users. At the moment I'm trying to figure out whether this issue is a bug and hopefully will be fixed in the next major version or it's something that I'm misunderstanding. Since the documentation is not clear maybe someone in the community could help me understand this.

Comment: Thank you for asking question. i have a problem like this, please tell me if you solved this problem. although i think problem will fix in iOS14. @lucianomarisi